# Xcode Cmd+Shift+J doesn't work after Cmd+Shift+O?

Tags: xcode

[image: Normally when we use Cmd+Shift+O search for a certain file & enter, the file path show like this, we can use Cmd+shift+J jump to project tree after that]

Normally when we use Cmd+Shift+O search for a certain file & enter, the file path show like above, we can use Cmd+shift+J jump to project tree after that

[image: Recently I use Cmd+Shift+O search for files & enter, the path looks like this, And Cmd+Shift+J responses nothing!!!!]

Recently I use Cmd+Shift+O search for files & enter, the path looks like above, the short one, and Cmd+Shift+J responses nothing!!!!

**I can locate the file manually in sidebar & search file in the input-field in the left-bottom, but that is really not convenience .

My Project tree contains a lot of sub projects, but no file can use Cmd+Shift+J reveal in project tree after Cmd+Shift+O locating it.

We use svn for code-manager, everyone in our team occur this problem, it sucks.**

I already tried stuffs following, and useless:

1. clean project
2. delete derivedData
3. delete main project & all sub projects' .xcworkspace & userData & sharedData
4. restart the macbook

I think it might be something wrong with the project settings? xcconfig?

Please save me...

Comment: Can you locate the file manually in the sidebar? If not, that may be the root of your problem.

Comment: I can locate the file manually in sidebar & search file in the input-field in the left-bottom, but that is really not convenience .

Comment: Just wondering whether the file was, in fact, accessible to the project. Another thing to try: move the project to another computer or at least a new user and try there. If it works there, maybe delete Xcode preferences ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: if this file was part of some framework header file, you may not able to get the proper path

Comment: My Project tree contains a lot of sub projects, but no file can use Cmd+Shift+J reveal in project tree after Cmd+Shift+O locating it.

We use svn for code-manager, everyone in our team occur this problem, it sucks.